# Android asks for USB permission twice

Tags: android, usb

I have a dev board running Android 4.0.4 and am using it as a USB accessory.  When I close the application on the board then plug in an Android phone over USB the board prompts "Open AppName when this USB device is connected?".  When I touch OK, the application launches and the popup is shown again, and it's also shown on the phone this time (but says accessory instead of device).

I am also noticing that when I plug in the device I receive the action `android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED` before I receive `android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED`, which seems like very strange behavior.

I can provide more details but I'm not entirely sure what would be helpful for debugging.  My question: What is causing this behavior?

Comment: Did you got any resolution? I am also facing this issue and is very annoying!

Comment: I did not  did you figure it out?